# Bluebird promises in loop

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have given a task to revive old javascript code. New system uses bluebird promises.
I have made a bit of changes to use them, but I got at this point, and I am not sure, if the way I am going to realize it, will be the best one.

Here I will show a snippet of the old code:

```
[...] // X0
.then(function(){
    [...] //X1

    // XXX
    if (assesment.data.AssesmentType == "1" || assesment.data.AssesmentType == "4") {
        for (var i = 0; i < assesment.data.Compartments.length; i++) {
            for (var b = 0; b < assesment.data.Compartments[i].Species.length; b++) {
                assesment.assortmentRow(assesment.data.Compartments[i].Species[b], false);
                // assesment.assortmentRow makes ajax request and does other studd
                // and now returns a promise
            }
        }
    }
    // X2
    if (assesment.data.AssesmentType != "2") {
        var asortRowRadioBtn = $("#assesment-assortment-compartments input[type='radio']").eq(0);
        asortRowRadioBtn.prop("checked", true);
        asortRowRadioBtn.trigger("click");
    }
    [...] //X3
});
```

What this code does actually is not important, for you to help. I have just added a comments, just to label blocks of code here (with `X0`, `X1`, `XXX`, etc)

In the old code, all those blocks were one after other. I had to split them, to use them with promises somehow.

So the question is - what to do with blob `XXX`

One thing I can think of -

```
[...] // X0
.then(function(){
    [...] //X1
    // new XXX 
    if (assesment.data.AssesmentType == "1" || assesment.data.AssesmentType == "4") {
        return Promise.each(assesment.data.Compartments, function(i) {
            return Promise.each(assesment.data.Compartments[i].Species, function(b) {
                return assesment.assortmentRow(assesment.data.Compartments[i].Species[b], false);
            });
        });
    }
     //X2 and X3 blobs wont be accessible here. 
     //So should I bring them inside next .then() function ? 
     //And is it OK for X1 blob and XXX to be in the same then()?
})
.then(function() ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost ready - you just need to put the code where it says `X2 and X3 blobs won't be accessible here` to a next `then` in the chain - since the `Promise.each` is (rightfully) in a `return` it won't reach that area.

```
[...] // X0
.then(function(){
    [...] //X1
    // new XXX 
    if (assesment.data.AssesmentType == "1" || assesment.data.AssesmentType == "4") {
        return Promise.each(assesment.data.Compartments, function(comp) {
            return Promise.each(comp.Species, function(b) {
                return assesment.assortmentRow(b, false);
            });
        });
    }
})
.then(function(val ) { 
    // x2 and x3 code parts go here, 
});
```

Comment: But is it valid, to put `X1` where it is, right? I am thinking about bringing it outside (before) anyway. Just like `X2`, it does not return a promise, but, imo, it looks ugly to split the code after `XXX` but not after `X1` just because it doesnt return a promise.

Comment: If X1 is sync and does not terminate control (return) then yes. If I may ask - is this code in NodeJS? If so, are you using a relatively recent version and not an ancient one? (Let's say 4+)

Comment: No, it is run in a browser for web page.

Comment: In that case - your code is pretty much the best you can do, although I think your `each` code is wrong - the `i` variable in your example is not the index but the compartment (the index is the second argument).

Comment: Also, you should probably not be making that many backend requests in a website anyway. You should fix your backend to accept multiple items at once instead.

Comment: Nice catch, that would have caused a headache to me. There are plenty of work left to do, to translate the old code to use promises. Before that is completed, I don't want to break it :> Thank you for help!